# Passing data from a WebApi Controller to an MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have data coming in to a WebApi controller which gets converted into a c# object, and I need to pass this to an MVC controller, at the moment I am holding this object in a static "Globals" class and then assigning an instance of my  ViewModel to that object in my MVC controller which then returns as usual. I'm aware of using TempData to pass data between MVC controllers. 
Is there a method to pass data between an APIController and an MVC controller? (I'm not using a database).

Here is the action in my APIController which gets the message by an external device:

```
    [Route("someroute"), HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] object obj)
    {
        try
        {

            MessageViewModel model = new MessageViewModel();
            model.Object = obj;
            Globals.model = model;
            return Ok();
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

I need to pass that model to my MVC controller.
At the moment I am storing it in a static class and then my MVC controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Globals.model);
    }
```

Is returning it when a client calls the action.

Comment: What say for `Session`?

Comment: Session like TempData isn't available in an apiController

Comment: Session in WebAPI - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/getting-started-with-Asp-Net-web-api-2-day-9/

Comment: I stand corrected, thank you, that seems more cumbersome though

Comment: Why not refactor out the logic in the mvc controller to some class that both the api and mvc controller can consume?

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing here: just instantiate the MVC controller and pass the c# object to the method as normal.  Obviously this would give you an ActionResult, but that matches your alleged requirement that you need to pass it to an MVC controller (ie this probably isn't the requirement with a bit of refactoring to a reusable class/method)

Comment: Please explain step by step what gets the data from the Web API, and how does it pass it to the controller. I.e. explain how the workflow looks like. Without knowing the workflow it's impossible to heklp you. What invokes the Web API action? What tries to pass the data to the MVC controller? How?

Comment: Okay so the action in the ApiController gets called when a message comes through from an external device, data from this message must be displayed in a view being returned by an action in the MVC controller, there is no fancy logic in my controllers, I just need the data passed in a better way than a static global variable.

Answer (score 1):

@peco is absolutely correct, you need to move logic outside mvc controller and reuse it in web api. If for some reason you cant do this, what preventing you from redirect with necessary parameters?

Comment: (reply to edit with provided code)I cant understand the end purpose of this design.You need database if you want to display some results generated by web api. Every time new request come to api controller the mvc controller will return different result.If this is what you need (save state of only one object,as example request counter) you can write it to text file (still database), other case you will lost your data while application restart